# Why does +!!{} equal to 1?

Tags: javascript-objects

I understand that it has a typeof Number because of plus before it and that it is an empty object.

```
+!!{} === 1
```

Comment: ! of any (also the empty) object is false, 
!false is true, 
+true === 1

Comment: @Turo you could post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` of any (also the empty) object is `false`

`!false` is `true`

`+true === 1`